# How to divide value percentage equally to rest of other input range element for making sum of all input range values 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello am creating a function for input range group and sum of all input range value should be 100.
Right now am able to make sum 100, But not able to divide values rest of other input ranges.

The function should be like this, When I increase one range by 10% and other should be decrease by 10%
equally. and when I decrease any input range by 10% other input range should be increase by 10% equally.

## CSS

```
.btn {
        background: #0075ff;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

## HTML

```
<div>Total : <span id="total">0</span></div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
    <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
    <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
     <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
    <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
     <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="5" class="price" />
    <div class="input-v">0</div>
</div>


    <br />
    <a class="btn">Calculate</a>
```

## jquery

```
  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
       
        var sum = 0;
        $('.price').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
            $('#total').text(sum);
        });

        if (sum > 100) {
            var p = sum - 100
            var q = sum - p
            $('#total').text(q);
            var r = $('.price').length;
            var t = parseInt(q / r);
            alert(t)
            $('.price').each(function () {
                var u = $(this).val();
                $('.price').val(u + t);
            });
        }
        
       

    })
```

Comment: why are you using jquery for such a think you can definitely use flex attribute on css to keep them alligned and with the same width without calculating it manually...

Comment: @MoussaBistami , No In need to divide value of all input ranges, Not to divide width